# How to add, fix and display text in image using HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have project in which I have to add text in image, After adding it will become new image and then I have to display new image.

I am able to get image and I can add the text in image.

HTML:

```
<img src="pic_mountain.jpg"  style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
<h2>A Movie in the Park<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 50px; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

my initial image is like:

[image]

After adding text it will look like:

[image]
now I need to fix this text for this image as a new image. I also want to use that new image for display without affecting original image.

Is there any solution for this?

If there any other way to add text using jquery or else, then please suggest me..

Comment: use an image editing tool - adobe photoshop or Gimp or the like.

Comment: Where do you want to use the new image, on the same page? Or do you want it saved to a local file or uploaded somewhere?

Comment: Since you are looking for a jQuery/CSS solution, I would say this is not possible. In order to actually melt the text and the image, you would have to create a new image file, which cannot simply be done with jQuery or CSS. 

What you could do however is either use a PHP API, since PHP can handle image files and add text to them with no problem. Or a bit more of an experimental approach would be to get the image information encoded in jQuery and manually manipulate the image data. I don't think that this is a doable approach though.

Comment: @cybrox that's not true, canvas (and in some extents svg) can do this without problem...

Comment: @Kaiido granted, that works. However, from the way the question is written, I assumed he also wanted the image to be _saved_ in order _to fix this text for this image as a new image_

Comment: @cybrox well canvas can do it to (and in some extents svg ;-) )

Comment: @cybrox I don't want to image to be saved.

Comment: @nnnnnn actually, I am getting image from database.it is just simple image.Now I need to select that image and need to add text i.e.10kg,5kg,.. then i need to display that updated image in different page.but in database original simple image will be as it is. I don't want to update image in database

Answer (score 0):

PHP has literally **COUNTLESS** libraries for doing just this but were all lazy and nobody wants to learn a new framework so heres some simple php functions to do just this

*Note: you would have to use php and then ajax to update it in real time i am unaware of any way to do what your asking in javascript*

```php
<?php
  $image_path = "images/image.jpeg";

  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'fonts/font.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "text to write to image";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Please not that this is an example using jpeg but php supports the exact same functionality for png,gif, and a few other image types

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can try to this way

```css
.imgSec { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.imgSec img{width:100%;height:228px;}
.imgSec h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 50px; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="imgSec">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnUj.jpg"  />
<h2>A Movie in the Park<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<div class="item">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GnUj.jpg"  style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
<h2>A Movie in the Park<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```

And the css is

```
.item { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50px; 
   left: 50px; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Canvas 2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/).

Two steps :

- use [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to draw your image.
- use [`fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) to fill your text.

Complete demo :

```js
/* okay there are actually a few more steps.. */

var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin ='anonymous'; // not needed if you're not using images from an other domain
img.onload = function(){ // remember to wait before your image has loaded
  // our canvas element
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  // its drawing context
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // don't resize the canvas with css
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0)
  
  ctx.font ='25px sans-serif';
  ctx.fillText('Hello world', 10, 40);
  // just using it as a backgroundImage to demonstrate that you can export the result, you could also just append the canvas into the doc, or use the `toBlob()` method for use with FileSaver.js e.g.
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+canvas.toDataURL()+')';
  out.href = canvas.toDataURL();
  };
img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1alt1303g9zpemd/UFBxY.png?dl=0';
```

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  }
```

```html
<a id="out"> show me an image instead </a>
```